# Adding image to a Plotly.js chart within a React component

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, plotly

I am having trouble adding background images to a plotly chart within a react component.

Consider [this](https://plot.ly/javascript/images/) example from plotly's website (second example on the page). When I try to replicate it within a react app I get the expected result *except* for the embedded image in the background:

[image]

The js logo above is not part of the plot - I've just added it to show that the image renders when outside of plotly.

Here is my app with two components ('Plot' and 'App'):

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Plot />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Plot.js:

```
class Plot extends React.Component {
  drawPlot = () => {
    Plotly.plot('plot', [{
      x: [1, 2, 3],
      y: [1, 2, 3]
    }], {
    images: [
        {
          "source": "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/js-logo.png",
          "xref": "x",
          "yref": "y",
          "x": 1.5,
          "y": 2,
          "sizex": 1,
          "sizey": 1,
          "xanchor": "right",
          "yanchor": "bottom"
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.drawPlot();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src="https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/js-logo.png"/>
        <div id="plot"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It seems that this is not the correct way to supply the image path in this situation but I'm struggling to understand why (and how to supply it correctly). Can someone help me understand this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the picture first, and then provide local src?

Comment: Yes, to no avail.